# Java IO Exception: Negative seek offset

Tags: java, seek

I have a program to replace contents in a file. But it results in a IO Exception, I don't know where I am making the logic wrong?

The code is shown below:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;

public class Test
{
   public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
   {
        File f = new File("test.txt");
        replaceAll(f, "hello world", "my world");
   }

       public static void replaceAll(File file, String oldText, String newText) throws Exception
    {
        int[] indices = findAllIndices(file, oldText);
        if(indices.length > 0)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<indices.length;i++)
            {
                replace(file, oldText, newText);
            }
        }
    }

        public static int[] findAllIndices(File file, String text) throws Exception
    {
        int[] indices;
        int index = -1, count = 0, i=0;
        String givenText = FileUtils.readFileToString(file);
        index = givenText.indexOf(text);
        while(index >= 0)
        {
            count++;
            index = givenText.indexOf(text, index+1);
        }
        indices = new int[count];
        index = givenText.indexOf(text);
        while(index >= 0)
        {
            indices[i] = index;
            index = givenText.indexOf(text, index+1);
            i++;
        }
        return indices;
    }

        public static void replace(File file, String oldText, String newText) throws Exception
    {        
        int index = findFirstIndex(file, oldText);
        if(index >=0)
        {
            RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
            raf.seek(new Integer(index).byteValue());
            String emptyString = fixedLengthString(" ", oldText.length());
            raf.write(emptyString.getBytes());
            raf.seek(new Integer(index).byteValue());            
            raf.write(newText.getBytes());
        }
    }    
}
```

The MWE is a part of a big code. The stack trace from the original code is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Negative seek offset
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.seek(RandomAccessFile.java:538)
    at org.javaextensions.FindAndReplace.replace(FindAndReplace.java:51)
    at org.javaextensions.FindAndReplace.replaceAll(FindAndReplace.java:76)
    at Test.main(Test.java:16)
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: Could you post the stacktrace please?

Comment: whats the value of index in raf.seek(new Integer(index).byteValue()); when the exception is thrown? I think it's negative... And that throws an I/O exception

Answer (score 1):

```
    public static void replace(File file, String oldText, String newText) throws Exception
{        
    int index = findFirstIndex(file, oldText);
    if(index >=0)
    {
        RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
        raf.seek(new Integer(index).byteValue());
```

Your problem is either here ^^

```
        String emptyString = fixedLengthString(" ", oldText.length());
        raf.write(emptyString.getBytes());
        raf.seek(new Integer(index).byteValue());
```

You should check the value of Integer(index.byteValue()) it is likely returning a negative number. Also, I don't know why you want to cast this to a byte, nor why you're creating an Integer object first. Neither should be necessary

Comment: I have added an answer. Please check

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are reinventing index value again. See below, your code contains array of those indexes:

```
int[] indices = findAllIndices(file, oldText);
```

You could pass the same while calling replace method as additional argument.

**Code changes to implement:**

```
public static void replaceAll(File file, String oldText, String newText) throws Exception
{
    int[] indices = findAllIndices(file, oldText);

    for(int i=0;i<indices.length;i++)
        replace(file, oldText, newText, indices[i]);
}

public static void replace(File file, String oldText, String newText, int index) throws Exception
{
    RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
    ..
    ..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the way that you generate the offset for your seek:

```
    if(index >=0) {
        ...
        raf.seek(new Integer(index).byteValue());
    }
```

You start with an index that is non-negative (fine) ...

But then you convert the index to a `byte`.

The problem is that Java bytes are in the range -128 to +127.  So what is most likely happening is that your positive integer gets converted into a negative byte value ... and then back to a negative integer.  For example the `int` 130 maps to the `byte` -126 and then back to the `int` -126

I don't understand the reason why you are converting the index to a byte at all, but if you are trying to "reduce" the index value to a number in the range 0 to 255, then you should do this:

```
        raf.seek(index & 0xff);
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though you are checking that index >= 0, you are not accounting for the case of index > 127:

```
    if(index >=0)
    {
        ...
        raf.seek(new Integer(index).byteValue());
        ...
    }
```

The range of a byte is -128 to 127.  If you take any int between 128 and 256 and try to get byteValue() you won't get a number greater than zero.
Try it:

```
    int i = 127;
    byte b = new Integer(i).byteValue();
    System.out.println("Value of b = " + b);
```

This results in b = 127.
Try it with i = 128 and you get b = -128.

- 1 - 127 are greater than zero.
- 128 - 256 are less than or equal to zero.
- 257 - 383 are greater than zero. ... and so on.